# Is it possible to send push notifications to the iPhone Simulator?

Tags: macos, iphone, apns

I am developing a push notification infrastructure and would like to test it with the iPhone Simulator on a Mac.

Is this possible, or do I need to use a physical iPhone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Push notifications don't work in the simulator.  You have to use a physical iPhone, iPod Touch, or iPad.

Good luck,

Mark

Answer (score -1):

You can test Push Notification using any button Click event.
First of all you have to create dictionary, like below.

```
NSString *StrTemp = @"{'aps':{'alert':'Test alert','sound':'default'}}";
NSData *tempData = [StrTemp dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSDictionary *testNotification = [NSJSONSerialization
                                  JSONObjectWithData:tempData
                                  options:0
                                  error:nil];
```

And you can send notification like below.

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] application:[UIApplication sharedApplication] didReceiveRemoteNotification:testNotification];
```